# this inquiry give me duplicate data

Tags: sql

This code gives me duplicated results.

```
SELECT store_sp.Partnumber
     , store_sp.ID
     , dbo.installed_sp.Installed_qty
     , dbo.store_sp.qty
FROM dbo.store_sp  
INNER JOIN dbo.installed_sp 
   ON dbo.store_sp.PartID = dbo.installed_sp.part_id 
  and store_sp.Partnumber = installed_sp.PartNumber
```

how can i solve it
https://ibb.co/n38xQk

Comment: The keyword `distinct` comes to mind.

Comment: Without understanding the cardinality between store_SP and installed_SP and the keys of both tables any answer provided is "Guessing."  While distinct will remove duplicates, it hides the underlying issue with your query.  If I had to guess the duplicates are because a part could be installed at different dates.  and thus the installed quantity may appear to be duplicated but is on different dates.  If you add additional data from installed_SP (such as `installed_SP.*`) i'm sure you'll see they aren't duplicates.

Comment: Alternatively you could be missing join criteria which is causing the duplicates.

Comment: @AhmedSalah If you have 2 rows in the installed table, both with a quantity of 2, do you want to see 2 or 4 as the result???

Answer (score -2):

You probably want a GROUP BY;

This will SUM the quantities in the rows you have called 'duplicates'. This is the best we can guess from your question so please try to provide more information...

```
SELECT store_sp.Partnumber
     , store_sp.ID
     , sum(dbo.installed_sp.Installed_qty) AS TotalInstalledQuantity
     , sum(dbo.store_sp.qty) as TotalQuantity
FROM dbo.store_sp  
INNER JOIN dbo.installed_sp 
   ON dbo.store_sp.PartID = dbo.installed_sp.part_id 
  and store_sp.Partnumber = installed_sp.PartNumber
GROUP BY
     store_sp.Partnumber
     , store_sp.ID
```

Comment: A guess at desired results but definitely better than distinct in this instance.